# Get the last inserted row id which is save through model in Yii1.1?

Tags: php, sql-server, model-view-controller, yii

I am using Microsoft SQL Server as my database and yii1.1 framework

```
$model = new Test(); 
$model->name = "test"; 
$model->save(); 
echo $model->id;
```

I can't get the id this way shown above the code. It doesn't return anything but the data is being saved to the database.

[image]

Here is my test class which I have generated through gii

```
    <?php
    class Test extends CActiveRecord
    {
        public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
        {
            return parent::model($className);
        }
        public function tableName()
        {
            return 'test';
        }
        public function rules()
        {
            return array(
                array('name', 'length', 'max'=>10),
                array('id, name', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
            );
        }
        public function relations()
        {
            return array(
            );
        }
        public function attributeLabels()
        {
            return array(
                'id' => 'ID',
                'name' => 'Name',
            );
        }
        public function search()
        {        
            $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    
            $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
            $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
    
            return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                'criteria'=>$criteria,
            ));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there some reason you've chosen Yii 1.1 instead of the current Yii 2.0 framework? Yii 1.1 went into maintenance mode back in 2016 and is very much stale and outdated.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71361793/edit) your question to include the contents of the Test class file (presumably protected/models/Test.php).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have added my test class. To let you know, I have tried with createCommand also data stores but can't get the last ID